# django: "'str' object has no attribute 'regex'

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm building a little web server using django but I keep getting `'str' object has no attribute 'regex'` in my template where it says `{% url 'signup' %}` and `{% url 'login' %}`. I guess this will be something to do with URL binding, or probably me not having imported the right module that is needed to refer to a URL by its name attribute. But I can't figure a way around this. Thanks in advance.

Template

```
{% include "header.html" %} 
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header"><h3>로그인</h3></div>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'login' %}" role="login">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>아이디</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="아이디를 입력하세요" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>비밀번호</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder=" 암호를 입력하세요" class="form-control" />
            <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                <input type="submit" value="로그인" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-default">가입하기</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% include "footer.html" %}
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from docx import Document
from exam.models import *

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')

def signup(request):
    try:
        if request.session["error"]:
            error_message = request.session["error"]
            del request.session["error"]
    except KeyError:
        error_message = None

    context = {
        "error_message" : error_message
    }
    return render(request, "signup.html", context)


def signup_submit(request):
    try:
        username = request.POST["username"].strip()
        password = request.POST["password"].strip()
        password_confirm = request.POST["password_confirm"].strip()
        full_name = request.POST["full_name"].strip()
        student_num = request.POST["student_num"].strip()

        if username and password and password_confirm and full_name and student_num:
            user = User(username=username, full_name=full_name, student_num=student_num)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return redirect("index")
    except KeyError:
        request.session["error"] = "올바른 요청이 아닙니다."
        return redirect("signup")
    else:
        request.session["error"] = "입력한 정보가 올바르지 않습니다."
        return redirect("signup")
```

URLS.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^signup/$', 'exam.views.signup', name='signup'),
    url(r'^signup/submit/$', 'exam.views.signup_submit', name='signup_submit'),
```

Error Traceback:

```
AttributeError at /
'str' object has no attribute 'regex'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.56.101:8000/
Django Version: 1.7.6
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'str' object has no attribute 'regex'
Exception Location: /home/web/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _populate, line 282
Python Executable:  /home/web/venv/bin/python
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955488/attributeerror-str-object-has-no-attribute-regex

Comment: @rmunn sorry but i don't think that really answers my question...

Comment: Try removing the include tags and see if that fixes it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13473949/django-url-template-tag-url-error-on-django-1-4

Comment: @bozdoz hmmm, nope that doesn't work. It is definitely something to do with {% url 'signup' %} because it works fine if I delete that.

Comment: Are you getting the above exception when clicking the below link <a href="{% url 'signup' %}" class="btn btn-default">가입하기</a> ?

Comment: @SrikanthBhandary actually i cannot even open the template.

Comment: Try getting the url from the path of the view `{% url 'exam.views.signup' %}`.

Comment: @JRodDynamite Nope. it's not working neither...is there something i should do before I call url by its name in views.py? For example, importing specific module or changing settings.py...etc

Comment: @Bossam try this .. <a href="{% url 'exam.views.signup' %}">가입하기</a>

Comment: @SrikanthBhandary not working neither...i am stuck on this problem for the last 3hours....

Comment: @Bossom  What if you remove the link? Is that working fine?

Comment: @SrikanthBhandary yeah i've changed the {% url 'signup' %} to "/signup". In other words referring directly and it works. But a new problem arose.....If I click the signup button 'str' object has no attribute 'resolve' error pops up...I'll have to figure that out myself. But thanks anyway

Comment: Everything seems correct. This is a long shot, but can you try reinstalling Django?